# Display Duplicate Records (TSQL)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, duplicates, rows

I am really struggling with an SQL query to return only duplicate rows, for example:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID   STORE_NO   REGION
2531047     1671         E05
2544970     1254         W09
2566618     1625         E01
2566618     1635         E01
2566618     1835         E01

Should look like:

EMPLOYEE_ID   STORE_NO   REGION
2566618     1625         E01
2566618     1635         E01
2566618     1835         E01
```

The above was acheived by the following:

```
SELECT 
   E.EMPLOYEE_ID,
   E.STORE_NO,
   S.REGION
FROM 
   [USICOAL].[dbo].[EMPLOYEE_STR_ASGN] AS E
RIGHT JOIN 
   [USICOAL].[dbo].[STORE] AS S ON E.STORE_NO = S.STORE_NO
ORDER BY EMPLOYEE_ID, REGION
```

I have tried various options but can only find a way to remove these duplicates, not display them only... Can anyone advise if the above is even possible?

Thanks in advance,
Charley.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM stuff st
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM stuff xx
        WHERE xx.employee_id = st.employee_id
        GROUP BY xx.employee_id
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
        )
        ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   E.EMPLOYEE_ID,
   E.STORE_NO,
   S.REGION
FROM 
   [USICOAL].[dbo].[EMPLOYEE_STR_ASGN] AS E
RIGHT JOIN 
   [USICOAL].[dbo].[STORE] AS S ON E.STORE_NO = S.STORE_NO 
JOIN 
   ( SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID 
       FROM [USICOAL].[dbo].[EMPLOYEE_STR_ASGN] 
      GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_ID 
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) DUPS 
 ON DUPS.EMPLOYEE_ID = E.EMPLOYEE_ID
ORDER BY E.EMPLOYEE_ID, REGION
```

And the right join could just be a join
If there is > 1 employee there is > 0 employee

Comment: Perfect! - I see where I was going wrong now when removing the duplicates too, thank you Blam!

Comment: If that was the answer you can indicate so by clicking the check